# Remove a line in a text if

Tags: java, line

Hi my problem is that I have a text with something like :

```
something1
[ something2
something3
[ something4
```

I  want to write a code in **java** that reads that text and search for a character, in this case "[", when it finds it, remove the entire line, in this case "[ something2"  , and then keep searching for that character so in the end I will be having something like this

```
something1
something3
```

I already search for something like this and I find this approach

```
File inputFile = new File("myFile.txt");
File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

String lineToRemove = "bbb";
String currentLine;

while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
    if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
    writer.write(currentLine);
}

boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

That code removes the entire line that haves in it "bbb", the problem here is that erases only the line that has in it only and elusively bbb
by example

```
something1
bbb
something3
bbb something
```

after run the code we have

```
something1
something3
bbb something
```

so I tried to modify the code to search for the character [ and then erases the entire line.
but I couldn't, so I was hopping that someone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

> that code removes the entire line that haves in it "bbb", the problem here is that erases only the line that has in it only and elusively bbb by example

- COZ of `if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;`
- `"bbb something".equals("bbb")` returns `false` and so the line is not skipped
- Use `regex` or `String.startsWith()` or `String.contains()` method

Try the following:

```
if(trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove)) continue;
```

**[EDIT]**
What I recommend is to implement KMP **[1]** in java (Pattern Matching). Will help you in future.

**[1]** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File inputFile = new File("myFile.txt");
File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

String lineToRemove = "bbb";
String currentLine;

while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
    if(!trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove))
    { 
      writer.write(currentLine);
    }
}

boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a Java program for this. Chances are you have an OS that knows tools like grep, awk, perl. For example

```
grep -v '^\[' infile >outfile
```

will copy the lines you want from file `infile`  to `outfile`

Comment: Linux is an IDE, all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the contains method.

```
while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // CHANGED EQUALS TO CONTAINS
    if(trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove)) continue;
    writer.write(currentLine);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: contains, with lower case

Comment: You are right :P Didn't see it was java. My bad. The colors of the code looks exactly like in VS :D